# Handling the differentiation of piecewise functions

Tags: calculus, derivatives

When I differentiate $\large f(x) = x|x|$ using the product rule i get:
$$\large f'(x)=x\frac{d}{dx}|x| + |x|$$
the problem is that the derivative of  $\large |x|$  is not defined when $\large x=0$:
$$\large \frac{d}{dx}|x|=\begin{cases}-1,x<0\\1,x>0 \end{cases}$$
so $\large f'(x)$ becomes:
$$\large f'(x)=\begin{cases}2x,x>0\\-2x, x<0\end{cases}$$
But in reality $\large f(x)$ is differentiable for $\large x=0$ 
You can correctly differentiate $\large f(x)$ by "merging" first the functions $\large |x|$ and $\large x$ into a single piecewise function:
$$\large f(x)=\begin{cases}x^2,x≥0\\-x^2,x<0\end{cases}$$
$$\large f'(x)=\begin{cases}2x,x≥0\\-2x,x<0\end{cases}$$

So, how can I differentiate piecewise functions like this one and always obtain the correct domain for the derivative? Is it enough to "merge" the functions and then check if the breakpoints are differentiable by checking if the left and right hand derivatives are the same?

Comment: Product rule requires both factors to be differentiable. So your first method cannot be applied for derivative at $0$.

Comment: The usual convention is $|x|' = \mathrm{sgn}(x)$, which vanishes at $x=0$ (because the absolute value has a minimum at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a perfect example of why we need rigorous mathematics. The definition of the derivative is as follows:

A function $f:D\to\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable at some point $a\in D$ iff the following limit exists:

$$f'(a)=\lim\limits_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$$

Now, we show that $f'(0)=0$ using this definition.

$$f'(0)=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{x|x|-0}{x-0}=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}|x|=0$$

As for the rest of the domain, your line of reasoning is correct concerning its derivative (looking at just the positive or just the negative numbers and deducing $f(x)=x^2$ when $x>0$). Examining what we did with the above analysis, it is essentially checking to make sure this limit exists (i.e., it is the same coming from both sides), so you are also correct in that regard.